# Kendo button should display record in kendo window using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC with Kendo UI for MVC. I have an Edit button that should display current record in Kendo Window. 
Here is my button:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Button()
    .Name("editButton")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button" })
    .Content("Edit Record")
    .Events(ev => ev.Click("onClick"))
```

)

Here is JavaScript code:

```
$("#editButton")
    .bind("click", function () {
        //alert("OK");
        location.href = '@Url.Content("~/Students/StudentDetails/EditStudentRecord?StudentID=" + @ViewBag.url)';
        //$("#studentWindow").data("kendoWindow").open();
    });
```

And this button should post id to this action method:

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult EditStudentRecord(int? StudentID) 
    {
        Student student = new Student();
        ViewBag.StudentID = new SelectList(db.Student, "StudentID", "UserName");

        student = db.Student.Find(StudentID);
        ViewBag.ShouldClose = false;
        return Json(student, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

but I get errors and can't get record in window.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What errors do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you are trying to do, it looks like you've got a few issues here.  Here is how I would solve this issue.

Change your `EditStudentRecord` endpoint to return a `PartialViewResult` instead of `JSON` as follows.

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult EditStudentRecord(int? StudentID) 
{
    Student student = new Student();
    ViewBag.StudentID = new SelectList(db.Student, "StudentID", "UserName");

    student = db.Student.Find(StudentID);
    ViewBag.ShouldClose = false;

    return PartialView("_EditStudentRecord", student);
}
```

Note you would need to create a new partial view, in my example called "_EditStudentRecord".

I would then create a Kendo Window, similar to the following:

```
@(Html.Kendo.Window()
    .Name("edit-student-window")
    .Title("Edit Student Record")
    .Width(400)
    .Modal(true)
    .Visible(false)
    .LoadContentFrom("EditStudentRecord", "StudentDetails", new { studentID = ViewBag.StudentID })
```

Then you would change the JS for your button to be similar to this (note I would probably change the name of this function, but since it's the name referenced in your Button, I left it).

```
function onClick() {
    $('#edit-student-window').data('kendoWindow').open();
}
```

Comment: Now I can Edit and save record through this window, but can't close it. I want, when user clicks save button, window should close and user be redirected to StudentDetails.cshtml page.

Comment: What kind of form are you using in the modal (on the EditStudentRecord partial view)?  An `Html.BeginForm()` or a `Ajax.BeginForm()`.

Comment: I am using Html.BeginForm(). It is working and I can save data in SQL Server. I just want form close when form is successfully updated/edited and data saved in record. Thanks